# How to revert a folder to a particular commit by creating a patch

Tags: git

Here's my history for the folder 'somefolder'

```
$ git log somefolder

commit 89cd
More changes to somefolder

commit ef47a
Updating somefolder and other stuff

commit e095
Bugs fixed in somefolder
```

I want to revert somefolder back to the 'Bugs fixed in some folder" commit.

Since the second commit involved changes outside of somefolder, I don't want to revert this commit.

I guess the safest way would be to create a diff/patch between commit e095 and 89cd that applies just to some folder, and then apply that patch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You can use [git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to update your repository to a specific state.

```
git checkout e095 -- somefolder
```

As for your question about generating the diff, that would work too.  Just generate the diff to go from your current state back to `e095`:

```
git diff 89cd..e095 -- somefolder
```

Comment: this doesn't remove files that were added in that commit, use `git reset e095 -- some/folder` instead

Comment: From git 2.22 you can use [`--no-overlay`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---no-overlay) for `git checkout` so that tracked files that are not in commit you are checking out from will be removed.

Answer (score 86):

You can use `git reset` to reset the index which will also include removing files that were added in more recent commits (`git checkout` on it's own doesn't do this):

```
git reset e095 -- somefolder
```

However `git reset` doesn't update the working copy and the `--hard` option doesn't work with folders. So then use `git checkout` to make the working copy the same as the index:

```
git checkout -- somefolder
```

and then if you also want to remove any files added you also need todo:

```
git clean -fd somefolder
```

Comment: this answer works for me when the directory include new files.

Comment: This answer is much better if you really want a clean snapshot of the repository at that time.

Comment: Much much better indeed !

Answer (score 0):

The `git restore` command is the command designed restore files and directories to the state they were in a different commit. If you specify a directory to restore, it will also remove files that were not present in the commit you are restoring from.

To restore the content of directory `somefolder` to the state it was in commit `e095`, you can run:

```
git restore -s e095 somefolder
```

By default, `git restore` restores content to the state it was in `HEAD`, but by using the `-s` switch (short for `--source`), we can restore content to the state it was in any commit.