# Git - revert everything under a specific directory to how it was at a given SHA

Tags: git

In git, how to I revert everything in a specific directory to how it was at a given SHA, leaving changes elsewhere in the repo untouched?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119036/how-to-revert-a-folder-to-a-particular-commit-by-creating-a-patch

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want:

```
git checkout REVISION -- path/to/revert
```

Just to play it safe, **save off your changes elsewhere before doing this**.  There's no way back if you have local modifications.

Comment: wow, your answer is way better :)

Comment: Will this be recursive?

Comment: Yes, it's recursive.